# MySQL replication working fine, but still shows "Waiting for master to send event" at 280000 seconds

Tags: mysql, replication

To repeat the title: MySQL replication working fine, but mytop still shows a thread "Waiting for master to send event". It has been like this for a few days, and is now at 280000 seconds. But replication is just fine.

I can see another thread which is doing the replication work, right now it is sitting on "Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it" but it has been running queries, and I can verify that the slave is up to date just by viewing the data.

Can I kill this process?

I recently had to re-set up replication, and that involved creating a new replication user, so I'm not sure if this is what has caused this "ghost replication process".

Comment: No, not really.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't you dare kill that process. Why ?

Run this query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user='system user';
```

The answer has to be two. Why ?

Standard MySQL Replication functions on 2 threads: 1) IO Thread, 2) SQL Thread. In my old post [Does MySQL support replicating all databases?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8934/does-mysql-support-replicating-all-databases/8958#8958), I explain the symbiosis between the two threads.

When you run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`, you will see three lines:

- `Slave_IO_Running: Yes`
- `Slave_SQL_Running: Yes`
- `Seconds_Behind_Master: 0`

This is the sign of a healthy replication process.If either `Slave_IO_Running` or `Slave_IO_Running` is `No`, then Replication is not running for one of six(6)reasons:

- Somebody ran `STOP SLAVE;`, which turns off both the IO Thread and SQL Thread
- Somebody ran `STOP SLAVE IO_THREAD;`, which turns off the IO Thread
- Somebody ran `STOP SLAVE SQL_THREAD;`, which turns off the SQL Thread
- There was a replication user authentication error, which turns off the IO Thread
- There was a network error, which turns off the IO Thread
- There was an SQL Error, which turns off the SQL Thread

When any of these cases show up, `Seconds_Behind_Master` is `NULL`.
What about the number `280000` ? That is simply the length of time (over 82 hours) that the IO Thread has been running. That's OK. It is not a ghost process. Replication requires an IO Thread to read binlog events from a Master's binary logs.

In conclusion, your IO Thread has been up for over 82 hours. Do not mess with replication.

Comment: Ah, awesome. Thanks for this important background info.

Answer (score 0):

In my case binary log position (through show master status) at master and Read_Master_Log_Pos (show slave status) at slave had a huge gap, i simply stopped the slave and start the slave. The difference decreased to nominal.